# Rails search with AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, search

I'm trying to implement the search function of the following rails cast:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax

But the thing is im using rails 4 and i can't seem to get it to work.

For instance this line of code doesn't seem to be executed at all:

```
$("#products").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("products")) %>");
```

But according to the tutorial it should be placed in the file: app/views/controllername/index.js.erb

which seems strange to me as well.

Thanks for helping out

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I'm using the following route for the controller im using.

```
type_regexp = Regexp.new([:courses, :institutes, :programmes, :staff].join("|"))
resources :browse_courses, only: [:show, :index], path: ':type', constraints: { type: type_regexp }
```

Im using one controller to display the information stored in 4 models and one of the four models is shown depending on the param :type

Comment: if you want more clear option = render 'index', :products => products

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
$("#products").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('products')) %>");
```

the products should be in single quotes rather than double quotes.

Comment: Changed it but it still doesn't look like the script is being run. I put an alert in there to check it but it doesn't fire.